# How I can get a instance by a class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method

```
 public static <T> T createObject(Class<T> t){

 }
```

You see, I want to get a instance of T.

I know this can be realized, because:

```
 public <T> T find(Object id, Class<T> type) {
  return (T) this.em.find(type, id);
 }
```

Help me........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

siunds like you need reflection

```
import java.reflect.*;
...
Class klass = obj.class;
Object newObj = klass.newInstance();
return (T)newObj;
```

note: written from memory, so the api may be slightly different.

Comment: The import is not needed, you aren't using anything from there. All you need is one method: Class.newInstance().

Answer (score 3):

If the class `t` has a no-args constructor, then the [Class.newInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method will do what is needed:

```
 public static <T> T createObject(Class<T> t) 
 throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return t.newInstance();
 }
```

Note that you have to either propagate or deal with checked exceptions arising from things like:

- the `t` object represents an interface or an abstract class,
- the `t` class doesn't have a no-args constructor, or
- the `t` class or its no-args constructor are not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want manage parameters, you can do that :

```
public static <T> T instantiate(Class<T> clazz, Object ... parameters) throws Exception {
    Validate.notNull(clazz, "Argument 'clazz' null!");
    if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(parameters)) {
        Class<?> [] parametersType = new Class<?>[parameters.length];
        for(int i=0 ; i<parameters.length ; i++) {
            parametersType[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
        }
        return clazz.getConstructor(parametersType).newInstance(parameters);
    }
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```